# Finding if EXISTS based on Multiple paired values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL statement that displays the following values, but the number of rows can be anything.

```
   SELECT NameID,Name,ValueID,Value FROM Options WHERE OptionID = 10000
```

Which results to:

```
 NameID  |  Name   |  ValueID  |  Value

 100     |  Color  |  10000    |  Black
 101     |  Size   |  10005    |  Large
```

Or sometimes even:

```
 NameID  |  Name   |  ValueID  |  Value

 100     |  Color  |  10000    |  Black
 101     |  Size   |  10005    |  Large
 102     |  Height |  10009    |  Tall
 103     |  Width  |  10006    |  Wide
```

I'm trying to write a Stored Procedure that can allow me to check if ALL of these value's exist based on OptionID

Therefore,

1. The statement would allow an input of `OptionID` of course to only show all the options inside the `Options` table for this `OptionID`
2. The statement would allow an input of multiple paired values for `NameID` and `ValueID`

The general logic needed would be something like this:

```
if ALL NameID and ValueID Pairs with-in an OptionID Exists
(as shown above in the results) 
   Then Return 'Unique Combination'
     Else Return 'Combination Exists'
```

Boolean would be fine as well. I've tried using a PIVOT to see if it can be done like this, but that was a bit more than i think i needed, but maybe not.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this homework? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: not homework, just stuck on it for a while.. =/  Need to know if all of these pairs exist within an optionID considering i can't just accept one value for `NameID` and `ValueID`, it is an x number of pairs that need to be checked against the results of the initial statement

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are looking for.  Try to make it a little clearer.  How do you know what all of the possible values are for an option id if they don't exist in the database?

Comment: @Chris: I was planning on passing `OptionID` `NameID`s and `ValueID`'s to an SP and it returns if it exists or not.  I would have the pre-existing combination from whats been generated already inside the app, so the app would know what needs to be selected.  You can view this question for more info if need be:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264439/how-to-find-the-unique-combinations-between-key-related-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if exists statement.

```
if exists(SELECT NameID,Name,ValueID,Value FROM Options WHERE OptionID = @optionID and NameId = @NameID and ValueID = @ValueID)
begin
   --do whatever you want
end
else
begin
   --do whatever else you want
 end
```

**Updated answer**

```
Declare @Loop as int,@POS int, @PAirs varchar(max),@CurrentPair varchar(max)
Declare @NameID as int,@ValueID as int, @Loop2 as int,@Pos2 int

SELECT @Pos = CHARINDEX(';', @Pairs, 1)
print @Pos
SELECT @Loop = CASE WHEN LEN(@Pairs) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    WHILE (SELECT @Loop) = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Pos = CHARINDEX(';', @Pairs, 1)
        IF @Pos > 0
            BEGIN
                set @CurrentPair = SUBSTRING(@Pairs, 1, @Pos - 1) --Here it is a comma delimited string such as 100,20000
                set @Pairs = SUBSTRING(@Pairs, @Pos + 1, LEN(@Pairs) - @Pos) --This takes the current pair away from original string

                SELECT @Loop2 = CASE WHEN LEN(@CurrentPair) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                While (Select @Loop2) = 1
                    Begin
                        SELECT @Pos2 = CHARINDEX('2', @CurrentPair, 1)
                        If @Pos2 > 0
                            Begin
                                set @NameID = SUBSTRING(@CurrentPair, 1, @Pos2 - 1)
                                set @ValueID = SUBSTRING(@CurrentPair, @Pos2 + 1, LEN(@CurrentPair) - @Pos2)

                                if exists(SELECT NameID,Name,ValueID,Value FROM Options 
                                            WHERE NameId = @NameID and ValueID = @ValueID)
                                    begin
                                        --pair found
                                    end
                                else
                                    begin
                                        --pair not found
                                    end

                            End
                        Else
                            Begin
                                set @Loop2 = 0
                            End
                    End
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                set @Loop = 0
            END
    END
```

Comment: How about matching the results of the query against an x amount of paired values?

Comment: you mean like a while loop? You can create a while loop in sql. The values would need to be sent as a delimited string, though, to the store procedure.

Comment: delimited string is fine, but there is paired values, so it would be like this i guess `100=10000,101=10005` and so on.

Comment: how many pairs will be sent to the sp at one time? are you sending multiple at once or you plan to hit the db for every pair?

Comment: it can be any amount.  the total number of them is pre-determined however, so it CAN be sent to the SP as well if needed.

Comment: ok, then I'd separate each individual parameter with a comma and then separate the pairs with a semi colon and break the string apart that way. The create a while loop that goes through each pair.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7693/discussion-between-eric-and-zee-tee)

Comment: I don't know how to `Split` or `Create a While WHERE Loop for Each Pair` =/

Answer (score 0):

I would do something based on `SELECT... EXCEPT SELECT...`. First, create and populate a temporary table with the passed-in name/value pairs, and then run something like

```
IF exists (--  Everything passed in
           SELECT select NameId, Name, ValueId, Value
            from @TempTable
           --  Then remove everything that is in the table
           except select NameId, Name, ValueId, Value
            from Options
            where OptionId = @OptionId)
    RETURN 'All items passed were not found for this OptionId'
ELES
    RETURN 'All items passed were found within this OptionId'
```

Fuss with this, I mistrust the meaning of those return labels.